# Probability of mining maximum of 3 block in next 20 minute

Tags: mining-theory, proof-of-work

I know that block interval in bitcoin blockchain is exponential distribution. Now I want to know what is the probability that maximum of 3 block will be mined in the next 20 minute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming block finding is a Poisson process with rate 1 per 10 minutes.

In that case, the number of blocks found per given finite time interval would be described by a Poisson distribution. For 20 minutes, a Poisson distribution with lambda = 20 minutes / 10 minutes = 2.

- No blocks in 20 minutes: ~13.53%
- 1 block in 20 minutes: ~27.07%
- 2 blocks in 20 minutes: ~27.07%
- 3 blocks in 20 minutes: ~18.04%
- 4 or more blocks in 20 minutes: ~14.29%

Due the memorylessness of the Poisson process, it doesn't matter when you start the clock for your 20 minutes. These hold for whatever window of 20 minutes you look at.